# How can I generate this matrix (containing only 0s and ±1s)?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I would like to generate  matrix of size `(n(n-1)/2, n)` that looks like this (`n=5` in this case):

```
-1     1     0     0     0
-1     0     1     0     0
-1     0     0     1     0
-1     0     0     0     1
 0    -1     1     0     0
 0    -1     0     1     0
 0    -1     0     0     1
 0     0    -1     1     0
 0     0    -1     0     1
 0     0     0    -1     1
```

This is what I, quickly, came up with:

```
G = [];
for i = 1:n-1;
   for j = i+1:n       
        v = sparse(1,i,-1,1,n);
        w = sparse(1,j,1,1,n);
        vw = v+w;
        G = [G; vw];        
    end
end

G = full(G);
```

It works, but is there a faster/cleaner way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`nchoosek`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) to generate the indices of the columns that will be nonzero:

```
n = 5; %// number of columns
ind = nchoosek(1:n,2); %// ind(:,1): columns with "-1". ind(:,2): with "1".
m = size(ind,1);
rows = (1:m).'; %'// row indices
G = zeros(m,n);
G(rows + m*(ind(:,1)-1)) = -1;
G(rows + m*(ind(:,2)-1)) = 1;
```

Comment: @lesspritfree Glad about that :-) In the last two lines you could also use [`sub2ind`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) instead of the sum

Comment: Wow. This is a real matlab'ed mindset! Very elegant.

Comment: @Mikhail Yeah. You probably miss some asterisks, `malloc` and loops here :-P

Comment: @LuisMendo  I write in C++, not in C, I may miss only some `new`'s, not `malloc`'s ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have two nested loops, which leads to `O(N^2)` complexity of non-vectorized operations, which is too much for this task. Take a look that your matrix actually has a rectursive pattern:

```
G(n+1) = [ -1  I(n)]
         [  0  G(n)];
```

where `I(n)` is identity matrix of size `n`. That's how you can express this pattern in matlab:

```
function G = mat(n)
  % Treat original call as G(n+1)
  n = n - 1;

  % Non-recursive branch for trivial case
  if n == 1
    G = [-1 1];
    return;
  end

  RT = eye(n);                 % Right-top: I(n)
  LT = repmat(-1, n, 1);       % Left-top: -1
  RB = mat(n);                 % Right-bottom: G(n), recursive
  LB = zeros(size(RB, 1), 1);  % Left-bottom: 0

  G = [LT RT; LB RB];
end
```

And it gives us `O(N)` complexity of non-vectorized operations. It probably will waste some memory during recursion and matrix composition if Matlab is not smart enought to factor these out. If it is critical, you may unroll recursion into loop and iteratively fill up corresponding places in your original pre-allocated matrix.

Comment: Good idea to use recursion!